# Can't update product information

Tags: prestashop, product

Long history with prestashop 1.7. All was fine with products over lot of versions, but now some strange problem appeared. When updating information on existing products, PS responds "Can not update product information" Makes Save button Grey. However, it saves changes in simple value fields (text, numbers). In case of creating or updating combinations nothing works.

PS 1.7.8.11 PHP 7.4
(but same problem was with 1.7.8.10 and PHP 7.3)

Products do not use attachments (not at all, no one of them). Appears in two shops one cloned from another, at first was OK, probably with version 1.7.6?,but now not any more).

Without debug it shows main.bundle.js error

```
VM532:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Debug gives different issue:

```
CRITICAL
10:47:44
php Call to undefined method Product::updateCacheAttachment()
Hide context    Hide trace
[▼
  "exception" => FatalThrowableError {▶}
]
{▼
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/classes/Attachment.php:225 {▼
    › 
    › Product::updateCacheAttachment((int) $idProduct);
    › 
  }
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/classes/Attachment.php:271 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/src/Adapter/Product/AdminProductWrapper.php:858 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php:574 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:151 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:200 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/admin/index.php:82 {▶}
}
CRITICAL
10:47:44
request Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "updateCacheAttachment" of class "Product"." at /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/classes/Attachment.php line 225
Hide context    Hide trace
[▼
  "exception" => UndefinedMethodException {▶}
]
{▼
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/classes/Attachment.php:225 {▼
    › 
    › Product::updateCacheAttachment((int) $idProduct);
    › 
  }
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/classes/Attachment.php:271 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/src/Adapter/Product/AdminProductWrapper.php:858 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/src/PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/ProductController.php:574 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:151 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:200 {▶}
  /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/admin/index.php:82 {▶}
}
]
```

What could be wrong and how to find the root cause of this problem?

All caches cleared disabled, all browser cache cleared - no change. Tested with PHP 7.3 no change. Also modified all keys in configuration.php to check cookie and token genereation - no change to error, cookies and tokens are generated ok.

Comment: "*What could be wrong?*" - `Attempted to call an undefined method named "updateCacheAttachment" of class "Product"`

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, this I can see from error message. However, no idea what is causing this and how to repair. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

JBW from Prestashop forum did give the right track to look for. There was old version of Product.php class file used. This had some code commented out and was the root cause of problem. Now problem resolved. Case closed.